# Program for visualizing trajectories for a 2D system of linear differential equations

Tags: technology-in-education, differential-equations

I am looking for a program so that when you give it a 2D system of linear differential equations and an initial condition, it can show an animation of the trajectory of a particle starting at that initial condition.

This program is close to what I want: [https://www.math.ksu.edu/~albin/teaching/math340/labs/10_eigenlines.html](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Ealbin/teaching/math340/labs/10_eigenlines.html)
but it only draws the trajectory lines. I want to show students how the point actually moves. Do any of you know if something like this exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already created something like this: https://trkern.github.io/eulersmethod

You can animate a point following a trajectory by adjusting the "animate trajectory" input number.

Note that this interactive (as the name implies) uses Euler's method to solve trajectories. If you need something more advanced, you'll have to use a computer algebra system.

Comment: Thanks @TomKern. This looks exactly like what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a GeoGebra one:

https://www.geogebra.org/m/vqn2mpgw

[image]

You can enter an autonomous system and move or animate a slider to show the evolution of the system. (It animates two trajectories.)

There is also a slider for a parameter.